# How to merge multiple files in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Very simple question! I want to merge multiple JSON files and the

Check this out:

```
f1data = f2data = f3data = f4data = f5data = f6data = "" 
 
with open('1.json') as f1: 
  f1data = f1.read() 
with open('2.json') as f2: 
  f2data = f2.read() 
with open('3.json') as f3: 
  f3data = f3.read() 
with open('4.json') as f4: 
  f4data = f4.read() 
with open('5.json') as f5: 
  f5data = f5.read() 
with open('6.json') as f6: 
  f6data = f6.read() 
 
f1data += "\n"
f1data += f2data += f3data += f4data += f5data += f6data 
with open ('merged.json', 'a') as f3: 
  f3.write(f1data)
```

And the output should be like this:

```
[
    {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "John",
    },

    {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "Tom",
    }
]
```

The problem is that Visual Code Studio brings up a red line under:
f1data += f2data += f3data += f4data += f5data += f6data

I have no idea why! And the code can't run! there is no error so i can troubleshoot..Any advice?

Comment: I would suggest to rename the post as "how to merge multiple Json files in Python" to be more clear and facilitate search. Adding json in tags as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is several points to improve in this code:

- You should consider doint it in a more "programatic" way:

  if you declare a list with the names of the json files you want to access like this:

  ```
  files_names = ["1","2","3","4","5","6"]
  ```

  you can then do:

  ```
  files_names = ["1","2","3","4","5","6"]
  data = ""
  for file_name in files_names :
     with open(file_name+".json" ,"r") as file_handle :
        temp_data = file_handle.read()
        data = data + temp_data 

  with open ('merged.json', 'a') as file_handle : 
    file_handle.write(data)
  ```

  which is more concise, more pythonic, and can be adapted easily if you ever need 7 json input files for example.
- If your files are always 1,2,3,4, you can also just do the for loop iteration like this: knowing the highest json file number you want

  ```
  max_file_name = 6
  for file_name in range(1,max_file_name):#i added 1 as first arg of 
  #range, assuming your files naming start at 1 and not at 0
     str(file_name) + ".json"
  ```
- To be sure your Json is a valid json, you could use the json standard library. It will take a little bit more time though, as the file will be parsed instead of just dumped into another one, but if you do not have 100000 files to merge and you don't know for sure the code that creates your json files in the first plase is valid, you souldn't see the difference

  To use it, just do

  ```
  import json
  max_file_name = 6
  data = ""
  for file_name in range(max_file_name):
     with open(str(file_name) + ".json" ,"r") as file_handle :
        temp_data = json.load(file_handle )
        data = {**data , **temp_data}
        # ** is used to "unload" every key value in a dict at runtime, 
        # as if you provided them one by one separated by comas :
        # data["key1"],data["key2"]...
        # doing so for both json objects and puttin them 
        # into a dictionnay is effectively just like merging them.

  with open ('merged.json', 'a') as file_handle : 
    json.dump(data,file_handle)
  ```

Comment: I would also recommend using the standard library's json module, rather than working directly with strings.

Comment: @AlonGadot I added your suggestion as a point of improvement of Ivy Knm's actual code.

Answer (score 1):

You have several ways:

```
with open('a', 'w') as a, open('b', 'w') as b, ..:
    do_something()
```

---

```
files_list = ['a', 'b', ..]
for file in files_list:
    with open(file, 'w')...
```

---

Use `contextlib.ExitStack`

```
with ExitStack() as stack:
    files = [stack.enter_context(open(fname)) for fname in filenames]
    # Do something with "files"
```

Answer (score 1):

The output to the 'merge' file won't be formatted **exactly** as you've specified but this shows the approach that I would personally use:-

```
import json
alist = []
with open('/Users/andy/merged.json', 'w') as outfile:
    for k in range(6):
        with open(f'/Users/andy/{k+1}.json') as infile:
            alist.append(json.load(infile))
    outfile.write(str(alist))
```